# I can't reach my website from this pc

Tags: networking

So I can't access my website that is hosted on a 20.04 ubuntu computer. I can't reach 192.168.0.1 sometimes either. I can access all the websites that I can't access from this PC with ubuntu from other PCs or phones. I tried to re-start and even re-install ubuntu and nothing happened.

Can anyone provide me a solution please? Id like to host my website on Ubuntu due to the quality of the software and the speed of loading. (Yes, I had a website hosted and it was working fine a while ago but I wiped my disk and re-installed the entire OS so that didn't affect me now)

Edit: I can't access localhost either. (My local ip adress is 192.168.0.151)

Comment: There is an insufficient amount of information here to even begin to offer a cromulent solution. Have you installed a web server, such as Apache? Have you confirmed the ports are open in UFW? By "can't access" do you mean there is a 404 error? A 500 error? Times out? There are a lot of ways for things to not work. Knowing what you've done, tried, and seen will make it much easier to offer something of value 

Comment: Also, we don't know if its a problem with the computer hosting the web site or your local computer that you're accessing it with (is the latter an Ubuntu machine?).  Or the network connection in between.  You will need to provide a lot more information...

Comment: I turned ufw off completely and I checked and I can access my website from my IP but not my local IP.